# Whenever there's a new number in a column, increment by 1

Tags: excel

I currently have three total columns in my excel sheet.
Im trying to map ID numbers.
Currently, when a column changes to a new number, I need a column to auto increment a new number.
My current set looks something like this:

```
ROW     Section
1   357307  
1   357307  
1   357307  
1   357307  
1   357307  
1   357307  
1   357307  
1   357307  
2   357308  
2   357308  
2   357308  
2   357308  
2   357308  
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
1   357309
2   357310
2   357310
2   357310
```

When the ROW column changes to a new number, even if it's a number that's already been used (like 1 or 2) I need the section column to increase by 1.

Comment: You can do this very easily with a simple formula. Have you made any effort to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: @KenWhite yes, I've tried running something like: =IF(D2<>A2,E:E,E2+1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell C3, enter this formula `=IF(A3<>A2, B2+1, B2)` and drag down. Or enter it in B3 if you don't want another column.

Comment: Hi this kind of works, but when I run that forumal, I am seeing this issue now: 357308
0
0
0
0
0
0
357308
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
357308

Comment: I did it and it worked perfectly. You sure you're entering the formula in the second row of data? The first row has to be a static number that the formula can start with.